# ASP.NET MVC - Check Box List for Link Table Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hoping someone can help me out, what I am trying to achieve a checkbox list (populated from a database table) which then inserts into a link table.

I'm not sure how best to achieve this, this is what I have so far which displays correctly, but I'm not sure how I can get this to save.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ReviewChecklistsController"))
    {
        foreach (var item in ViewBag.ChecklistId)
        {
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           name="@item.Value"
                           value="@item.Value" /> @item.Text
                    </label>
                </div>
            }
            <p></p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save Checklist" />
            </div>
        }
```

Below is how I have set it up in the database, if you need any more information please let me know. I am using Entity Framework. [image]

What I want is ReviewChecklist\ChecklistId to map to List_Checklist\ChecklistId and then State is just a boolean so if the checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: What do you get in the controller?

Comment: Nothing, just an empty model.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working using the below. Is this okay, or is there a better way to do it?

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ReviewChecklistsController"))
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in ViewBag.ChecklistId)
        {
            var nameStatus = "reviewChecklist[" + i + "].Status";
            var nameReviewId = "reviewChecklist[" + i + "].ReviewId";
            var nameChecklistId = "reviewChecklist[" + i + "].ChecklistId";

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReviewId, new { Name = nameReviewId })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChecklistId, new { Name = nameChecklistId, Value = item.Value })

            <p>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Status, new { Name = nameStatus })
                @item.Text
            </p>

            i++;
        }
        <p></p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save Checklist" />
        </div>
    }
```